# Nmap- what are the top 100 ports scanned

Tags: nmap

I am new to nmap and i read that you can limit the output of nmap to the top 100 ports by using the command -F such as:

```
nmap -F <IP>
```

My question is what are the top 100 ports. I have been looking everywhere but cannot find it. Appreciate if anyone can point me to the right direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [nmap man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/nmap.1.html):

> Nmap needs an nmap-services file with frequency information in order to know which ports are the most common. If port frequency information isn´t available, perhaps because of the use of a custom
>   nmap-services file, -F means to scan only ports that are named in the services file (normally Nmap
>   scans all named ports plus ports 1–1024).

Further googling returns this file: https://svn.nmap.org/nmap/nmap-services

Comment: You can see exactly which ports are scanned with this command: `./nmap -F -oG - 0.0.0.1 -v` (The IP address `0.0.0.1` is reserved, and should cause an error instead of a port scan, to save time in this particular case)

Answer (score 1):

nmap comes with a list. Here's the list in descending order of frequency. The `-F` option scans the top 100 on this list:  [Google Sheets » port_open_freq](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r_IriqmkTNPSTiUwii_hQ8Gwl2tfTUz8AGIOIL-wMIE/pub?output=html)

Answer (score 0):

This fast scan will look at the top TCP and UDP ports most commonly found to be open following research by [Gordon Lyon](http://insecure.org/fyodor/). The default scan looks at the top 1000 while in the past:

> ...The first 1024 ports as well as all named ports above 1024 were
>   scanned (1715 TCP and 1488 UDP).

The fast scan is a further reduction and scans the most common of the 1000 most common.

Source: [jahboite.co.uk](http://jahboite.co.uk/blog/2008/09/nmap-4-75-new-features.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know concretely which ports have been scanned, then let nmap create an XML-output file and within that search for the scaninfo tag.